# Commenting Generics - Is it possible to refer to generic type parameter not as T but as its actual type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, generics, comments

Given a method like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a <see cref="T1"/>, return a <see cref="T2"/>.
/// </summary>
public T2 ExampleMethod(T1 t1)
{
   // omitted
}
```

can I write a comment such that Visual Studio will correctly display it, if T1 is an `int` and T2 is a `string`, for example? Or, am I stuck with T1 and T2 appearing in the comment?

Said differently: is there something I can do so that in Visual Studio, the tooltip on this method shows the actual type names?

**Edit:** I seem to have not explained what I'm actually interested in knowing.

Suppose I have a class called `Widget<T1,T2>`. Suppose I have a method like the one above.

Then, when I do

```
Widget<int,string> myExample = new Widget<int,string>();

myExample.ExampleMethod(... );  // HERE - if I mouse over the method  

// I get a tooltip. Is there something I can do to the comment in my 
// example method above that will allow me to say 
// "Given a System.Int32, return a System.String"?
```

**Edit 2:** Someone commented here a moment ago but their comment was deleted. They suggested I use

```
///Given a <see cref="T1"/>, return a <see cref="T2"/>.
```

Which is what I'm using now. This is fine. My question, phrased differently for the third time now, is Visual Studio smart enough to infer what T1 and T2 are from a constructor? *I* can figure out what T1 and T2 are from the method signature, and I thought maybe Visual Studio could do the same and support this in the comment.

My gut feeling is no, but hence the question.

Comment: why use generics if you already know the type?

Comment: @ZachSpencer Suppose I want to use a generic class for a variety of types. I'm just interested in knowing if there is a way to get Visual Studio to correctly substitute type names in comments.

Comment: How can even visual studio know it will be `int` and `string`?

Comment: @Jonesy If he does, he wouldn't be asking this question in first place ;)

Comment: @Jonesy I've edited my question to be more clear. Obviously the whole point of generics is that we don't know the type until compile time. I realise that and my question is a bit more nuanced than that.

Comment: That does make a lot more sense now

Comment: I take it you mean comments for the purpose of intellisense on members of typed instances of this class? I don't think so, otherwise .NET framework classes would implement it. For what it's worth, it seems like an excellent feature request.

Comment: @esmoore68 You got it! Good point, if it existed, the framework would be using it but that's not the case. I wonder if JetBrains might be able to implement something like this?

Comment: I don't believe VS can do this today, but it seems like an excellent feature request. I don't think you should need to have to do anything with the XML comments themselves; the IDE should simply infer the appropriate type names in the displayed tooltip, the same as it already does now for method parameters and return types. You might consider submitting it as an actual feature request on the Microsoft Connect web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Visual Studio does not support that. You should ask yourself why you would want to use the specific type in your comments.

A good method documentation is done by describing it function in non-technical terms. And describe its parameters by using clear names and a good description what is expected of that parameter. The type is hardly ever need. If you do need it, you probably are trying to document your methods in a thechnical way, which is hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: Yes, but comments should not contain questions, additional information for a question or (in)complete answers. Comments should be used to challange people to improve their questions or answers. There was not answer for your question so I provided one. It is up to you to accept it, or comment on it so I can improve it.

Comment: "No" is the correct answer, so I've accepted it. The reason I asked if you read the comments was that there were other people who misunderstood my question (resulting in me editing my question multiple times) before they finally grokked what I was asking for. *Of course I understand the point of generics*.  But for complicated method signatures, I'm asking why VS only infers types for the method signature and not the comments. Some commenters here noted that this would indeed be a useful feature. Again, to answer your question: *that's why*.

Comment: In documentation it would not be useful, but it would be in the intellisense tooltip. When intellisense shows the method signature for the first Edit above, it replaces the types T1 and T2 with int and string but the method description provided by the XML comments just read "T1" and "T2".

Answer (score 4):

To supplement @Martin Mulder's answer as well as a couple of the comments for this question, I have submitted a problem report to the Visual Studio developer community to fix this "issue" as a feature request. I have basically requested that the Intellisense, when hovering over a statement that substitutes a generic for a specific type, shows the specific type in the comments when using the `<typeparamref name=""/>`  tag in the comments. I am not sure if doing the same when using `<see cref=""/>` is appropriate, but if you feel like it is, feel free to add a comment to the problem report to request its inclusion in a fix!

[Substitute Generics For Actual Type In Intellisense For XML Comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/638896/substitute-generics-for-actual-type-in-intellisens.html)